# Placing matching occurrence number to the left side of the occurrence itself

Tags: awk, sed, regular-expression, replace, numbering

I have a file with multiple occurrences of the expression ".mp3". I want the first occurrence to become "1.mp3", the second occurrence to become "2.mp3", and so on.

It would be something like awk '/ mp3 / NR' file

My file:

```
line 1
wget .mp3 url
line 2
wget .mp3

....
```

I haven't got any results

Comment: Asked and answered at https://stackoverflow.com/q/57847550/1745001 - please don't multi-post.

Comment: @EdMorton, Thankful. Now that the question has been answered I will delete the replicated question there. I do not know if a multi-post is wrong, if you can point this out in the guidelines of this forum I am grateful that I can know the limits of my actions :)

Comment: I'm not going to look for it in guidelines for this forum - not multi-posting has been part of all online forums etiquette since the 1990s. Just google `netiquette multiposting`

Answer (score 1):

```
$ awk -v i=1 '/ \.mp3/ {sub(/ \.mp3/," "i++".mp3",$0)};1' input.txt
line 1
wget 1.mp3 url
line 2
wget 2.mp3
```

If the numerals in the wget URL are meant to be zero-padded, you can use awk's `sprintf()` to format `i` with leading zeroes. For example:

```
$ awk -v i=1 '/ \.mp3/ {sub(/ \.mp3/," "sprintf("%03i",i++)".mp3",$0)};1' input.txt
line 1
wget 001.mp3 url
line 2
wget 002.mp3
```

You could also combine `sprintf()` with `wget`'s `-O` (`--output-document`) option to save the downloaded files with zero-padded filenames, so they sort correctly (e.g. 01,02,03,...10 instead of 1,10,2,3,...)

```
$ awk -v i=1 '/ \.mp3/ {sub(/ \.mp3/," "i".mp3 -O "sprintf("%03i",i++)".mp3",$0)};1' input.txt
line 1
wget 1.mp3 -O 001.mp3 url
line 2
wget 2.mp3 -O 002.mp3
```

---

All of the above one-liners will output to stdout.  To overwrite the original, redirect to a new file and either `mv` it or overwrite the original.

```
awk -v i=1 '/ \.mp3/ {sub(/ \.mp3/," "i++".mp3",$0)};1' orig.txt > new.txt
```

and then either:

```
mv new.txt orig.txt
```

This will replace `orig.txt` with a new file created with the permissions specified by the current `umask` value.  It may also have a new owner and/or group (depending on who runs it, and what their default group is).   It will also have a new inode number, breaking any hard-links that might exist.

Most programs that have an "in-place edit" option (e.g. `sed -i` or `perl -i`) do this.  In most cases, this is fine because it's being run by the same user with the same umask as the original file's owner, and few files have multiple hard links.

or

```
cat new.txt > orig.txt
rm new.txt
```

This will overwrite the contents of `orig.txt` with the contents of `new.txt`, and then delete `new.txt`.  `orig.txt` will have the same inode, owner, group, and permissions as before.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
i=1;
while [ "$( grep -o ' .mp3' file)" != "" ];
do
 sed -i "0,/ .mp3/ s/ .mp3/ $i.mp3/" file
 i=`expr $i + 1`;
done
```

Comment: Works but a wee bit more complex and probably slower than cas' `awk`solution which by itself (tx `awk`!) only ever applies where the record matches. No need for the `while "Is there a match?"` test in that case. Anyway, +1 on didactic grounds and because the answer certainly   does not deserve a downvote  ;-)